# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named pickle for py3.7

Tags: python-3.x, import, pickle

I am receiving this error from command prompt: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pickle'` running in python 3.7,

I have it setup like this:

`import pickle as thisPickle`

What can be the reason why I having this import issue, appreciate any help. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pickle` is a part of the Standard Library and is pre-included in the Python package. There should not be a reason that it does not work. Make sure that **no other versions of python exist on your computer**. The command prompt may be using outdated versions that still exist. Also, see if other modules install correctly on your machine.